# R - plot and axes

Tags: r, plot

I have x and y and I need to make a plot of every (x,y) pair, then split both axes for exact 1000 parts and check in which square do I have most points on the plot.

```
x <- rexp(10000,2) 
y <- rnorm(10000)
```

I tried to use this and split the axes depending on x and y I get:

```
plot(x,y, xaxt="n")
axis(1, at = seq(from = ..., to = ..., by = ...))
axis(2, at = seq(from = ..., to = ..., by = ...))
```

I'm not sure if it is correct? And then how do I get square with the largest amount of points?

Comment: What do you mean 'do I get square with the largest amount of points? Your data has 10000 number of rows. Splitting it by 1000 parts will lead to equal chunks of sub-data which are 1000 rows each.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility to solve the problem. Probably there are more elegant (and faster) ways to do this because I'm a beginner myself.

---

I take it that you want to split both the range of x and y into k=1000 parts of equal length. Consequently, you will get 1000² rectangles and every point will belong exactly to one of the rectangles.

```
k<- 100 %number of parts on each axis [k=1000 in your case but then there is not much to see in the graph]

widthx=(range(x)[2]-range(x)[1])/k

widthy = (range(y)[2]-range(y)[1])/k

plot(x,y)

abline(h=min(y)+widthy*(0:k))

abline(v=min(x)+widthx*(0:k))
```

To find out which rectangle contains the largest number of points, we calculate for each rectangle how many points are in there but checking that the x-coordinate and the y-coordinate are in the corresponding range.

```
s=matrix(data=NA,nrow=(k-1),ncol=(k-1))

for(i in 0:(k-1)){
    for(j in 0:(k-1))
    {
        s[i,j] <- sum(x>(min(x)+i*widthx) & x <= (min(x)+(i+1)*widthx) & y>(min(y)+j*widthy) & y <= (min(y)+(j+1)*widthy))
    }
}

max(s,na.rm=FALSE) %maximum number of points
m<-which(s==max(s,na.rm=FALSE), arr.ind = TRUE) %in which square is the maximum
```

The rectangle with the most points has lower left corner

min(x)+m[1]*widthx;min(y)+m[2]*widthy